# Swagger UI NotFoundException in Quarkus package with dev profile activated

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi, quarkus

I've developed a Quarkus app with some addons:

`[agroal, cdi, config-yaml, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, hibernate-validator, jdbc-h2, jdbc-postgresql, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, security-jpa, servlet, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-jwt, smallrye-openapi, vertx, vertx-web]`

When I run the app with `mvn quarkus:dev` all runs perfect (Swagger UI runs in normal URI `http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/`). Also when I package the code (`mvn package`) and then run the jar with `java -Dquarkus.profile=dev -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`, everything seems good:

```
2021-10-04 12:38:48,844 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) app 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.2.3.Final) started in 3.641s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2021-10-04 12:38:48,844 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated.
```

But Swagger UI not starts and when I try access it with the browser, I receive a 404 error with this message:

```
RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/
```

I can watch this in the log:

```
2021-10-04 12:39:00,454 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-0) RESTEASY002305: Failed executing GET /q/swagger-ui/: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:70)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:47)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:480)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:332)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:253)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.service(ResteasyFilter.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.sendError(ResteasyFilter.java:76)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:172)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:31)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:593)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:119)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
        at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5$1.run(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:415)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The application file contains this (I use YAML format):

```yaml
"%dev":
  quarkus:
    log:
      level: DEBUG
    swagger-ui:
      enable: true
```

Steps to reproduce:

First part (development mode)

1. `mvn quarkus:dev`
2. In a browser, go to: http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/. Response code 200: OK.

Second part (package mode)

1. `mvn package`
2. `java -Dquarkus.profile=dev -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`
3. In a browser, go to: http://localhost:8080/q/swagger-ui/. Response code 404: NotFound.

I don't found some similar question. Can any help me?

Answer (score 0):

This property needs to be set to `true` [`quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include`](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-swaggerui_quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include), in application.properties or in build time with: `mvn package -Dquarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true`. Only then, you can activate or not with the property `quarkus.swagger-ui.enable`.